# Difference Between Oil Filters

Tags: oil-filter

Are there any differences between one brand of oil filter and another?  For example, I see that an "original" Mazda oil filter is twice the price as a generic brand.

Comment: This isn't an answerable question as written.  Could you be more specific about what you're trying to find out?  As is, this is very similar to asking "Are there any differences between cars?"

Comment: @BobCross I guess I'm trying to find out if an oil filter is a fairly standard, generic part like a nut or bolt, or is there a significant difference between one oil filter and another.  Is that any better?

Comment: Not really: what are your requirements?  Are you looking for a filter that is equivalent to your original part when used as documented in the "regular usage" portion of your owners manual?  Or are you planning to race this car?  Specificity is your friend here: if you limit the question, you're more likely to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Are there differences in oil filters? Absolutely. You need to understand what the function of the oil filter is.

Oil carries contaminants away from the bearing surfaces in the engine and pump it through the filter to remove them. An oil filter is filled with some sort of filtration media. It is arranged in pleats to give it more filtration area. Generally there will be some sort of band to keep the pleats separate so they won't bunch together. If this happens, you lose filtration area. Most generic filters will have less filtration area and maybe more banding, some have a bypass valve, some don't. The bypass valve acts when the filter stops up. It allows the oil to bypass the filter so the engine won't lose lubrication.

The only real way to compare a filter is to cut it open and compare the filtration media. Take the pleats and spread them out. Compare them to an OEM filter. A good way to compare is to weigh them. If the filter is shorter, smaller in diameter, or lighter, you probably are not getting what you should have. Remember if the filter doesn't do it's job, you are just pumping contaminants back into the engine.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely.  OEM filters for one particular car of mine have an anti-drainback valve, whereas aftermarkets do not (including some expensive ones).  Quality of materials used and filtration can vary wildly while still being "acceptable".

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I'm going to attempt an answer, and I'd like to encourage other members to edit and perhaps make this a canonical Q&A: Yes, there are differences between one brand of oil filter and another.

In reference to your comment above, if you put the wrong grade material nut or bolt in the wrong application, you'll find out that fasteners are not very generic, though there are standards for manufacturers are supposed to follow, typically determined by the cryptic stamps on them. There are unreliable manufacturers of these items, so those buying directly from factories do tests to verify the standards are being followed, then we all buy the fasteners from these trusted resellers.

There are generally certain features that an OEM filter will have, such as a bypass with a certain relief setting, threads that match, size that fits in the engine compartment, flow ratings that match, etc. An after market filter that states it is "OEM equivalent" is probably just claiming to meet similar minimum requirements, but this is not going to have anything to do with filter media efficiency.

It is much more difficult to tell when a filter is not meeting some minimum standard than a fastener, because even if the filter catastrophically fails, there may no way to tell, other than increased wear on an engine that is running unfiltered oil (e.g. all oil flowing through the bypass), and especially difficult when the oil is actually being changed regularly.

As to whether or not the filter media of one brand is as efficient as another, that's another story. For comparing filter brands, Google is your friend. I have my opinions, but I recognize that's all they are, thus not appropriate for an SE Q&A site.

Comment: "An after market filter that states it is "OEM equivalent" is probably just claiming to meet similar minimum requirements, but this is not going to have anything to do with filter media efficiency." - citation needed.  What evidence supports the word "probably" in this sentence?

Comment: @BobCross Personal experience as a buyer for one of the world's largest after market motorcycle parts distributors, as well as 9 years experience as an agent for various Chinese parts manufacturers. If you have contradicting information, please provide it.

Comment: Even so, I'm not sure how your writ answers the question. Most everything you have written is generality. In [this article](http://www.thermoscientific.com/content/dam/tfs/ATG/CMD/CMD%20Documents/Application%20&%20Technical%20Notes/D19486~.pdf), an OEM Equivalent part as "... one which is manufactured to meet the performance specifications of the original manufactured part and should post similar performance metric results ...". To me this includes efficiency. I respect your experience, but this is the reason I stayed away from this question in the first place. Hard data is needed.

Comment: @Paul, personal assertion is not evidence.  An objective (e.g., double blind) comparison of a set of oil filters would certainly allow us to draw conclusions about which of those specific filters are actually "OEM equivalent."  We still wouldn't be able to generalize to the point where "OEM equivalent" == UNSAT.  The problem is still the word "probably" above and the burden of proof isn't on me.

Comment: @Paul, if you'd like to have an open-ended discussion, you are welcome to do so in the chat.

Comment: @Paul Maybe you could edit your question to include details of the labs you have hired and the testing they did.